# Can I remove the Hamburger (drawer navigation icon) from the toolbar, removing the area of it (rectangle)?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-toolbar, drawerlayout

I want to remove the hamburger and the rectangle area of it, but I just can't.

A lot of answers out there are saying to use "setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false)", but I think this is not what I want, or if it is, I'm not using correctly.

> When the indicator is disabled, the ActionBar will revert to
>   displaying the home-as-up indicator provided by the Activity's theme
>   in the android.R.attr.homeAsUpIndicator attribute instead of the
>   animated drawer glyph.

The thing is, I want to remove it, not just show the navigation arrow.

Comment: Just don't use an `ActionBarDrawerToggle`. That's pretty much all it's for, is to provide that button. You may also need to remove some other `ActionBar`/`Toolbar` calls, depending on your setup, but we'd have to see your code to be certain.

Comment: You are right, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sole purpose of an `ActionBarDrawerToggle` is to enable that button to open/close the drawer of a `DrawerLayout` with a click. If you don't want that functionality, you can just remove the `ActionBarDrawerToggle`. The user will still be able to drag the drawer per usual, and you can still open/close it programmatically with the appropriate `DrawerLayout#openDrawer()` and `DrawerLayout#closeDrawer*()` methods.

If you've also used another method that enables a navigation/up button - e.g., `ActionBar#setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled()` or `Toolbar#setNavigationIcon()` - you'll need to remove that, as well, to completely get rid of the button.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. You just need to remove any code for the `ActionBarDrawerToggle`, and the home button setup. There's no new code to add. For example, in [this sample shown on the developer page](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html#ActionBarIcon), you'd remove everything in `onCreate()` after the `mDrawerLayout = ...` line, and all of the `mDrawerToggle` method calls in the `Activity` overrides after that. That's it.